# How to split a line at a vertex in QGIS 2.2?

Tags: qgis-2

Is there a plugin out there that will split a polyline at vertexes?  My arcgis license isn't high enough to run the tool.  I'm using 2.2.

Comment: Yes this is an exact duplicate.  There IS a solution in SEXTANTE in QGIS so the answer below is misleading (although OpenJump is yet another option of course).  Also check out [ET GeoTools](http://www.ian-ko.com/) for a free plugin to ArcGIS.

Comment: However, the answer to the old question does not seem to be valid for the recent QGIS 2.0 versions where the old Sextante tool is placed into another place in the QGIS menus with different name, and it also works nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

I found this tool with a bit different name from the Processing menu from QGIS 2.2 Windows 32-bit stand-alone installation. It is now in the **Processing toolbox - QGIS Geoalgorithms - Vector geometry tools  - Explode lines**

My old answer was:

It looks like the processing algorithm "Split polylines at nodes" has not been converted from SEXTANTE into QGIS Processing tools yet. I can find the tool from SEXTANTE toolbox in OpenJUMP, gvSIG and Kosmo GIS.

If you just want your lines split into segments it is a simple operation with OpenJUMP

[image: OpenJUMP extract segments tool]

[image]